# Match and merge two data frame by string matching

Tags: r, merge, match

I have two dataframes that I want to merge together, however I want to merge them by districts. The only problem with this is that the district names in one dataframe may have extra white spaces, commas, different upper-case/lower-case letters, or added words. So I wanted to match the two based on the main district name. for example:

```
df1
County of Herefordshire

df2
Herefordshire, Count of

#merged together pick the first data frame name

df12
County of Herefordshire
```

I had thought that `charmatch` would work, wile it does it seems to only work for complete matches and I lose many matches as a result.

Any suggestions?

Reproducible code:

```
#Dataframe 1
structure(list(UK_Districts = c("Aberdeen City", "Aberdeenshire", 
"Abertawe - Swansea", "Adur District", "Allerdale District (B)", 
"Amber Valley District (B)", "Angus", "Argyll and Bute", "Arun District", 
"Ashfield District", "Ashford District (B)", "Babergh District", 
"Barking and Dagenham London Boro", "Barnet London Boro", "Barnsley District (B)", 
"Barrow-in-Furness District (B)", "Basildon District (B)", "Basingstoke and Deane District (B)", 
"Bassetlaw District", "Bath and North East Somerset", "Bedford (B)", 
"Bexley London Boro", "Birmingham District (B)", "Blaby District", 
"Blackburn with Darwen (B)", "Blackpool (B)", "Blaenau Gwent - Blaenau Gwent", 
"Bolsover District", "Bolton District (B)", "Boston District (B)", 
"Bournemouth, Christchurch and Poole", "Bracknell Forest (B)", 
"Bradford District (B)", "Braintree District", "Breckland District", 
"Brent London Boro", "Brentwood District (B)", "Bro Morgannwg - the Vale of Glamorgan", 
"Broadland District", "Bromley London Boro"), `2018` = c(8L, 
2L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L
)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

#Dataframe 2
structure(list(UK_Districts = c("Adur", "Allerdale", "Amber Valley", 
"Arun", "Ashfield", "Ashford", "Babergh", "Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barnet", "Barnsley", "Barrow-in-Furness", "Basildon", "Basingstoke and Deane", 
"Bassetlaw", "Bath and North East Somerset", "Bedford", "Bexley", 
"Birmingham", "Blaby", "Blackburn with Darwen", "Blackpool", 
"Blaenau Gwent", "Bolsover", "Bolton", "Boston", "Bournemouth, Christchurch and Poole", 
"Bracknell Forest", "Bradford", "Braintree", "Breckland", "Brent", 
"Brentwood", "Bridgend", "Brighton and Hove", "Bristol, City of", 
"Broadland", "Bromley", "Bromsgrove", "Broxbourne", "Broxtowe"
), population_2018 = c(63869, 97527, 126678, 159827, 127151, 
129281, 91401, 211998, 392140, 245199, 67137, 185862, 175729, 
116839, 192106, 171623, 247258, 1141374, 100421, 148942, 139305, 
69713, 79530, 285372, 69366, 395784, 121676, 537173, 151561, 
139329, 330795, 76550, 144876, 290395, 463405, 129464, 331096, 
98662, 96876, 113272)), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to join them cleanly. You can try `fuzzyjoin` package. In the code below, I joined the two dataframes based on the string distance of the two `UK_Districts` columns. There are several string distance algorithms available in the `method` parameter of `stringdist_full_join()` or its variant. Here, I used Jaro–Winkler distance. Through eye-balling, a threshold of 0.25 seemed to give a reasonable match.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

distance_join_df <- stringdist_full_join(
  dat1 %>% select(UK_Districts),
  dat2 %>% select(UK_Districts),
  by = "UK_Districts",
  method = "jw", distance_col = "dist"
) %>% 
  arrange(UK_Districts.x, dist) %>% 
  group_by(UK_Districts.x) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(UK_Districts.y = if_else(dist < 0.25, UK_Districts.y, NA_character_)) %>% 
  left_join(dat1, by = c("UK_Districts.x" = "UK_Districts")) %>% 
  left_join(dat2, by = c("UK_Districts.y" = "UK_Districts"))

distance_join_df

# # A tibble: 40 x 5
#    UK_Districts.x            UK_Districts.y  dist `2018` population_2018
#    <chr>                     <chr>          <dbl>  <int>           <dbl>
#  1 Aberdeen City             NA             0.340      8              NA
#  2 Aberdeenshire             NA             0.340      2              NA
#  3 Abertawe - Swansea        NA             0.389     14              NA
#  4 Adur District             Adur           0.231     14           63869
#  5 Allerdale District (B)    Allerdale      0.197     14           97527
#  6 Amber Valley District (B) Amber Valley   0.173     14          126678
# <Omitted>
```